# Wpf: привязка данных из объекта

Tags: c#, framework, wpf, .net, binding

Есть отдельный класс `Piple` с кучей данных о человеке, я создаю объект этого класса в `MainWinow`. В главном окне приложения у меня множество различных texbox, для этого объекта (имя, фамилия и т.д.). Можно ли как-то использую `Binding`, сделать так, что бы при изменение объекта изменялись бы данные в соответствующих `textbox,` и наоборот, при изменение в `textbox`, изменялись бы соответствующие поля в `Piple`?

Вот код  класса `Piple`:

```
namespace WpfApplication4
{
    public class Piple 
     {          
        public string name;
        public string name2;
        public Piple()
        {   
            name="Иван";
            name2="Иванов";
        }    
    }
}
```

Код главнного класса C#:

```
  namespace WpfApplication4
  {
        /// <summary>
        /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            Piple chel = new Piple();
            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.DataContext = this;                    
            }
         }
}
```

Код окна на XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"

        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"  WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid >

        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="28,76,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>


        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="28,135,0,0"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Нужно соответственно привязать данныйе из `chel.name` и `chel.name2` к соответствующим `textbox`. Подскажите можно ли это сделать с помощью `Binding`?

Answer (score 8):

1. Привязка к полям класса в WPF невозможна, Вам нужны хотя бы свойства (property).
2. Чтобы при изменении свойств класса новые значения отображались в контроле, нужно чтобы класс был наследником интерфейса INotifyPropertyChanged
3. Вы сами биндинги-то не прописали у TextBox'ов.

Все это должно выглядеть как-то так:

```
    public class People : INotifyPropertyChanged // Наследуемся от нужного интерфеса
    {
        // Ваши поля 
        private string name, name2;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; // Событие, которое нужно вызывать при изменении

        // Для удобства обернем событие в метод с единственным параметром - имя изменяемого свойства
        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            // Если кто-то на него подписан, то вызывем его
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        // А тут будут свойства, в которые мы обернем поля
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                // Устанавливаем новое значение
                name = value;
                // Сообщаем всем, кто подписан на событие PropertyChanged, что поле изменилось Name
                RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        public string Name2
        {
            get { return name2; }
            set
            {
                // Устанавливаем новое значение
                name2 = value;
                // Сообщаем всем, кто подписан на событие PropertyChanged, что поле изменилось Name2
                RaisePropertyChanged("Name2");
            }
        }
    }
```

В коде контрола создаем экземпляр класса и прописываем DataContext (на самом деле DataContext можно прописать и в разметке контрола):

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            // Создаем экземпляр нашего класса
            P = new People(){Name = "Ololosha", Name2 = "Trololosha"};
            InitializeComponent();
            // Устанавливаем как контекст данных
            DataContext = P;
        }
```

А в разметке контрола прописываем TextBox'ы:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name2}"/>
```

Вот теперь оно будет работать так, как вы хотите.

Еще наверное надо упоминуть о таком свойстве биндинга как `UpdateSourceTrigger`. Оно описывает когда надо изменить источник. По умолчанию у TextBox'а стоит значение `LostFocus`, т.е. изменение произойдет только когда TextBox потеряет фокус. Если Вы хотите, чтобы изменения происходили сразу же, то Вам нужно `UpdateSourceTrigger` установить в `PropertyChanged`:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Я бы Вам посоветовал найти хорошую книжку по WPF. [Вот тут](http://professorweb.ru/) есть довольно неплохой сайт о WPF (и не только о нем), по крайней мере мне в свое время он очень помог